# SQL query separating the first row from the rest

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Been struggling with this for a while, I basically have a list of names in the database for a given id, and I want to select the first name for an id into one column, and the rest of the names for an id into a comma separated other column. The second column is queried as follows:

```
SELECT KittyName as KittyName, rowNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By (select 1) ASC) FROM 
           (SELECT
                (
                    SELECT KittyName + ','
                    FROM KittyNameTable
                    where KittyNameTable.Id = OtherKittyData.Id
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ) as CombinedKittyNames
           ) as t2 WHERE rowNum > 1
```

This query runs **without the rowNum clause** producing two columns:

```
KittyName   rowNum
Fluffy       1
Jeff         1
Jeff         2
Marcus       1
```

but when I include it it says rowNum is not a column.

I've tried a few things but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: try to give `alias` to this `rowNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By (select 1) ASC)`  `as rowNum` and then put it in `where` clause  `WHERE rowNum > 1`

Comment: Have tried the `as rowNum` instead of `rowNum =` but the result is the same

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what is your question. But why didnt you use `TOP` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use an alias defined in a `select` in the `where` clause.  Use a CTE or subquery instead:

```
WITH cte as (
      SELECT KittyName as KittyName,
             rowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By (select 1) ASC) 
      FROM (SELECT
                (
                    SELECT KittyName + ','
                    FROM KittyNameTable
                    where KittyNameTable.Id = OtherKittyData.Id
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ) as CombinedKittyNames
            FROM OtherKittyData
           ) as t2
     )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rowNum > 1;
```

As a note:  you probably don't want a comma at the end of the list.  Also, it is safer to convert the XML from the XML type to a character string, so characters such as ampersands are not converted to `'&amp;`.  This query would look like:

```
WITH cte as (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By (select NULL)) as rowNum,
             STUFF((SELECT ',' + KittyName
                    FROM KittyNameTable
                    WHERE KittyNameTable.Id = OtherKittyData.Id
                    FOR XML PATH('concat'), TYPE
                   ).VALUE('/concat[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
                   1, 1, '') as CombinedKittyNames
      FROM OtherKittyData
     )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rowNum > 1;
```

EDIT:

If you want all Kitty Names except the first, then you have the `row_number()` in the wrong place.  Hint:  when asking a question, include sample data and desired results.

```
      SELECT okd.*,
             STUFF((SELECT ',' + KittyName
                    FROM (SELECT knt.*,
                                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By (select NULL)) as rowNum
                          FROM KittyNameTable knt
                         ) knt
                    WHERE knt.Id = okd.Id AND
                          rowNum > 1
                    FOR XML PATH('concat'), TYPE
                   ).VALUE('/concat[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
                   1, 1, '') as CombinedKittyNames
      FROM OtherKittyData okd;
```

In other words, you have to do the filtering *inside* the subquery.

By the way, you shouldn't use `order by` with a constant in this case.  There is no "first" row.  You should use an explicit ordering column (such as an id).

Comment: I gave it a go but the results were not what I expected. I'm in way over my head on this one. The idea is it joins all the kitty names except the first one, as that is selected into a different column, but this code seems to not be doing that because it joins it all together before the rowNum is evaluated to skip the first record.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select KittyName, RowNum
from
    (SELECT KittyName as KittyName, rowNum
           (SELECT
                (
                    SELECT KittyName + ','
                    FROM KittyNameTable
                    where KittyNameTable.Id = OtherKittyData.Id
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ) as CombinedKittyNames
           ) as t2 ) as x
 Where RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Same issue regardless of `rowNo =` or `as rowNo`